# What happens to non-expendable items pulled from Deep Pockets?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, prestige-class, pathfinder-society

The Prestige Class [Pathfinder Chronicler](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/prestigeClasses/pathfinderChronicler.html#pathfinder-chronicler) gets the following ability at level 1:

> **Deep Pockets (Ex):** A Pathfinder chronicler collects items as well as lore, picking up small amounts of this or that throughout her travels. As a result, she may carry unspecified equipment worth up to 100 gp per class level. This can be any kind of gear that can reasonably fit into a backpack, including potions and scrolls (but not any other sort of magic item). As a full-round action, the chronicler may dig through her pockets to retrieve an item she specifies at that time, deducting its value from the allocated amount of cost. This item cannot weigh more than 10 pounds. When the total remaining cost reaches 0, the chronicler can retrieve no more items until she refills her deep pockets by spending a few hours and an amount of gold to bring her total up to 100 gp per class level.
>
> In addition, if she takes 1 hour to pack her gear each day, she gains a +4 bonus to Strength to determine her light encumbrance. This does not affect her maximum carrying capacity. The efficient distribution of weight simply encumbers her less than the same amount of weight normally should. Finally, the Pathfinder chronicler gains a +4 bonus on Sleight of Hand checks made to conceal small objects on her person.

As an example, my Pathfinder Society party discovers that a pair of manacles would be handy. I use a full-round action to retrieve common manacles with an average lock, decreasing my Deep Pockets stash by 55 gold. By the end of the scenario I am able to retrieve the manacles. What happens to the manacles at the conclusion of the scenario? I see three options:

1. I keep the manacles, add them to my chronicle sheet and inventory tracking as a purchased item. These can now be resold at half price, allowing me to recoup 27.5 gold
2. I lose the manacles. They are treated as an expendable item that has a duration of that scenario.
3. The manacles are redistributed into my Deep Pockets funds. I recoup the full cost of the manacles straight into deep pockets.

Of these, I think #3 is least likely. However, I can see arguments for the other two. Since the ability doesn't specify any of this, I assume #1 is correct. In this case, Deep Pockets works like a delayed store and any items retrieved are added to inventory.

Keeping in mind I'm looking for a Pathfinder Society level answer, is my assumption correct? If none of these are correct, what happens to non-expendable items pulled from Deep Pockets?

---

Note: I'm not asking about how the credit is spent or replenished; that is clear in the rules. I'm looking for clarification as to what happens to non-expendable items at the conclusion of a Pathfinder Society scenario.

Comment: Are there other abilities similar to this one that work differently *because* they're being used in Pathfinder Society? That is, what makes you think the special ability must have an effect other than what's printed? (Or is there an exploit that you're hesitant to reveal lest it color the answers?)

Comment: @HeyICanChan As I was talking to some other players about using this prestige class, they thought in a home game they would rule that the items are treated as expendable (i.e.: #2 above). This character is in PFS, so I wanted to make sure they hadn't put something in place to limit this. There's no exploit here, but I'd hate to be losing value by retrieving non-expandable items that disappear at the end of a session.

Comment: That seems harsh. Why would the other players think the fetched items expendable? You paid for the item, after all. In fact, you *prepaid* for the item! If you never used your ability, you could've spent all that money instead on real, permanent gear. Besides jealousy, why punish you because *you* have a class feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All items from your pockets are items that you bought before, at an unspecified time, you just didn't record them on your character sheet until you took it out of your pockets.

Which means that those items must be registered as *items purchased with gold* just as if you had bough them before or after the scenario. And thus, it must be **recorded on your Chronicle sheet** with it's full value, and these items can be sold for half value just like any other item.

Searchign through the [Pathfinder Society](http://paizo.com/pathfindersociety)'s messageboards or playing guide, i found t[his explanatory post from a Venture Agent](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2qox4?Contentious-Topic-Are-items-on-a-Chronicle#13), that lists what is possibly to obtain from *Deep Pockets*. Everything leads me to think that **the GM should treat this ability like your character had purchased those items before the scenario**, because that is exactly the concept of these abilities.

Now, if the item is expendable, you treat it as an expendable (a potion or scroll), and you could not write it down on your sheet, and simply pay for it using *Prestige Points* at the end of the scenario.If it's non-expendable, you treat it as such, and write it down on your chronicle sheet using up the correct value from your *Deep Pockets* ability, or pay with your own money at the end of the scenario (which results in the same), but you should **keep this item and record it on your sheet**.

For the sake of this answer, i will also include the halfling's racial feat, [Well Prepared](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/well-prepared/), and the very similar feat available from [Ultimate Intrigue](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9j6p?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Ultimate-Intrigue), [Brilliant Planner](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/brilliant-planner/).

Answer (score 4):

Deep pockets is... very similar to an in-game store in a video game, like the Steam store or whatever. You can’t buy things from it with regular money, but you can buy things with store credit, and you can buy store credit. Your class level gives you free store credit, and your free store credit also serves as a cap on the credit you can buy.

So, for example, as a 1st-level chronicler, you have 100-gp-worth of deep pockets credit, as well as a 100-gp limit on how much deep pockets credit you’re allowed to have. When you pull out a set of manacles, you have “bought” those manacles with 55-gp-worth of deep pockets credit, leaving 45-gp-worth of credit remaining. You own those manacles now, you can do whatever you want with them, including sell them to a real store for real gp.

But your limit is still 100-gp-worth of deep pockets credit. You can buy additional deep pockets credit with your regular gp, effectively spending money to ensure you’ll continue to pull out useful tools.

Comment: *Your own portable shop* is exactly how a lot of people seems to define this ability, the hafling racial, and the new feat available from ultimate intrigue. All of them allow you to buy unspecified things before adventuring and deciding what you actually bough when a situation arises.

Answer (score 0):

As a GM, I'd say that the Deep Pocket credit (I like KRyan's term) is expended with every item you pull out (consumable or not).  However I would allow the character to put gold back into that account (up to the limit).

The amount of GP per day would depend on a lot of factors.  A day of dedicated shopping in a decent sized town would be 20% of the total credit limit per day.  Bigger cities allow you to refill more quickly.  You would refill more slowly if you aren't spending any real time at it (you would likely still pick up things as you come across them).

Comment: @Shadowcat, the thing is that how you spend your money buying things works differently on pathfinder society. Take a look on the Guide, it can be found on the link i put on my answer: http://paizo.com/pathfindersociety